# Gerar valores float entre -1 e 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Estou a tentar gerar valores `float` entre -1 e 1 para testar se estes se encontram dentro dos limites definidos de modo a criar um vetor com a quantidade de dados que pretendendo só que apenas estou a conseguir gerar valores `float` entre 0 e 1 através da função `random()` na função que defini, sei que existe a função `uniform()` mas não estou a conseguir introduzi-la na função `criavetor(dados)`, o meu código é o seguinte:

```
from random import random # para gerar os nums aleatorios com ponto flutuante

"""
Valores de Teste 
"""
"""
Função de criação de vetor de valores aleatórios entre 0 e 1
"""
"""
Limites 
"""
limite_max=0.8# limite máximo
limite_min=-0.8# limite mínimo

"""
Gerar valores para teste 
Função de criação de vetor de valores aleatórios entre 0 e 1
"""
def criavetor(dados):
    val=[]
    for i in range(dados): # fazer isto (N) vezes
        val.append(random()) # adiciona o numero seguinte gerado aleatoriamente entre 0 e 1 ao vetor vec  
    return val
"""
# Inserção da quantidade de valores a gerar
"""
dados = int(input('Quantidade de valores a serem gerados:'))
val = criavetor(dados)# a variável global val é igual aos dados da função criavetor(dados)
"""
Comparação entre os valores gerados e os limites máximo e mínimos
se os valores estão dentro dos limites definidos estão OK, se estiverem fora desses limites estão NOT OK
"""
for x in val:
    print("\n")
    print("O valor de x é: ", round(x, 3))    
    if x >= limite_min and x <= limite_max: 
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("NOT OK")
```

a saída quando executo o código é a seguinte:

```
Quantidade de valores a serem gerados:5


O valor de x é:  0.522
OK


O valor de x é:  0.973
NOT OK


O valor de x é:  0.122
OK


O valor de x é:  0.218
OK


O valor de x é:  0.74
OK
```

Comment: Na documentação diz: "Return the next random floating point number in the range [0.0, 1.0)". Tente usar outra função do módulo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se já consegue gerar os positivos, não vou entrar no mérito se está certo ou não, é pura matemática, em vez de gerar de 0 à 1 você gera de 0 à 2, aí subtrai 1, então fica de -1 à 1. Eu faria assim, mas parece que idiomaticamente a recomendação é o uso do método [`uniform()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform):

```
import random

print([random.uniform(-1, 1) for _ in range(20)])
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1Z2SLy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nobvapob-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/RandomUniform.py).

Comment: O módulo random de Python provê várias funções para gerar números e outras opções aleatórias como são necessários. No caso, a distribuição `random.uniform` aceita os limites menor e maior para uma faixa numerica. Em quase todas as outras linguagens, a geração de números aleatórios está restrita a valores entre 0 e 1, e o programador tem que transformar o número depois - mas é um dos fatores "batteries included" responsável pelo sucesso do Python. (random.uniform é o de menos, mas as amenidades `random.choice` e `random.shuffle` realmente fazem diferença )

Comment: E tem alguma vantagem real e clara? Ou só porque já tem e dá na mesma?

Comment: vantagem funcional não - mas é uma das características da linguagem: deixa você se preocupar com o seu problema - as coisa óbvias e pequenas você não tem que ficar refazendo.  Em qualquer revisão de código a sugestão forte seria pra trocar para o random.uniform.  Ao meu ver, uma resposta bem legal aqui teria que explicar "como é feito em outras linguagens" e "o Python já faz isso com `random.uniform`   )

Comment: @jsbueno Pronto então

Answer (score 7):

É só ler a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) daquilo que você está utilizando.

> `random.random()`
>
> Return the next random floating point number in the range [0.0, 1.0).

Traduzindo, retorna o próximo número aleatório com ponto flutuante dentro do intervalo [0.0, 1.0). Lembrando que o parêntese limitando o 1.0 no intervalo indica que este valor não será incluído.

Enquanto

> `random.uniform(a, b)`
>
> Return a random floating point number N such that a <= N <= b for a <= b and b <= N <= a for b < a.

Traduzindo, retorna um número aleatório com ponto flutuante N de forma que a <= N <= b para a < b e b <= N <= a para b < a. Perceba que, diferente do `random`, os extremos do intervalo são incluídos pelo `uniform`, podendo retornar -1.0 ou 1.0.

Leia a documentação para mais detalhes sobre questões de arredondamentos ao utilizar essa função.